# Spring java config - create list of beans also created in runtime

Tags: java, spring, config, javabeans

I have a list of gaming rooms which is created by Spring. Each rooms corresponds some rules (which is enum), and the code is:

```
@Bean
List<Room> rooms() {
    return Arrays.stream(Rules.values())
        .map(rule -> new Room(rule))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

But now I need the rooms to be `@Beans` too: I want Spring to process `@EventListener` annotation in them. However, I don't want to declare them manually in config as the `Rules` enum can be updated in the future. How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

It can be accomplished by invoking another method which is marked with `@Bean` i.e. creates `Room` bean as shown below

```
@Bean
List<Room> rooms() {
    return Arrays.stream(Rules.values())
        .map(rule -> room(rule))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

@Bean
Room room(Rule rule) {
    return new Room(rule);
}
```

This should suffice without need of `@EventListener`.

Let know in comments if any more information is required.

Comment: If the `room()` bean's scope is not specified, all the rooms in list have the same rule: `Rules.values()[0]`. So I have to mark the `room()` bean as `@Scope("prototype")`, right?.
But after I send the event it has to proceed, I get exception: `Error creating bean with name 'room' defined in ApplicationConfig: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'room' parameter 0; nested exception is NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'Rules'`. Also my IDE argues that for `room()` bean there are no candidates as a parameter.

Comment: Yes, the bean scope should be `prototype`. Also regarding the error are the method `public` ? (*not sure though about this*)

Comment: Methods are package-private, but that doesn't matter - if it did, I would get the exception at startup

Comment: okies.. could you try with `public` method access and also re-compile with arguments names preserved

Comment: @Bond-JavaBond, Thanks for the answer, but the fact is it will try to create each Room with same spring-bean name as "room" as per the second method name, hence only the first Room will be created. At least this is something happenning with me. Any idea on that?

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, there is another option

```
@Bean
List<Room> rooms() {
  return Arrays.stream(Rules.values())
    .map(rule -> {
        Room r = room(rule);
        this.beanFactory.initializeBean(r, <some unique name>);
        this.beanFactory.autowireBean(r);
        this.beanFactory.registerSingleton(<same name>, r);
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private Room room(Rule rule) {
  return new Room(rule);
}
```

within a @Configuration class having,

```
@Autowired
private ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory;
```